# Elixir Enum map

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm preparing data for the `<%= select f, :subject_id, subjects_to_select(@all_subjects) %>`
where subjects_to_select is:

```
def subjects_to_select(subjects) do
   subjects
   |> Enum.map(&{&1.title, &1.id})
   |> List.flatten
end
```

However, is it possible to show not only title (in selector), but also other variables? From the db I return `select: %{title: p.title, teacher: u.surname, lvl: p.lvl, id: p.id}`, and I need to provide something like lvl, title. But with the current setup, I can only see title in the selector. I've checked [Enum on hex](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2), but still struggle. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def subjects_to_select(subjects) do
  subjects
  |> Enum.map(&{"#{&1.title}/#{&1.lvl}", &1.id})
end
```

I guess something like this should work, if I got your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Everything works now. Have a great day!